# Chart Series By Region in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, chart

I've wrote a code for modis ndvi timeseries(code below). But it returns error in chart creating (ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion) : Error generating chart: Invalid argument specified for ee.Number(): system:time_start

```js
var regions = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(    // forest.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(geometry), {label: 'forest'}),
    ee.Feature(    // crop.
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(geometry2), {label: 'crop'})
  ]) ;

var modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
.filterDate("2000-01-01","2017-12-31");



var mod13 = modis.map(function(img){
  var id = img.id();
  img = img.select("NDVI").rename(id);
  return img.multiply(0.0001)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});

print(mod13);

var timeseries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  mod13,regions,ee.Reducer.mean(),250,'system:time_start','label')
  .setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions({
    title : 'vegetation series',
    xAxis : {title : 'time'},
    yAxis : {title : 'NDVI'},
    lineWidth : 1,
    pointSize : 2,
    series : {
      0 : {color : 'red'},
      1 : {color : 'green'}
    }});

print(timeseries);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well clearly the charting function is not happy with the input arguments. While creating `mod13`, you renamed all the NDVI bands to corresponding dates (not sure why you would do that, because chart uses dates from the `system:time`). Images within the collection `mod13` doesn't contain a unique band name.

Now when you call `ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion`, it is expecting the following order of arguments: `imageCollection, regions, reducer, band, scale, xProperty, seriesProperty`. At the place of `band` it finds `250` which is the scale. So you have two options:

1. Use `ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(mod13, regions, ee.Reducer.mean())` with first three arguments, assuming you don't want to change the scale
2. Do not rename the NDVI band in `mod13` and use 
   `ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(mod13, regions, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'NDVI', 250, 
   'system:time_start', 'label')`

See https://code.earthengine.google.com/9f86ca8486070c7f440c3fa1ea02dd4b for complete example.

PS. Your code is not exactly reproducible. `geometry` and `geometry2` are not defined.